# Android: blinking flash light

Tags: android, flash

I am trying to make a blinking flash light without camera, but the problem is that once the blinking is started I cannot touch the stop button, so the app goes forever.

My code:

```
  SurfaceHolder mHolder = preview.getHolder();

                    mHolder.addCallback(MainActivity.this);

                    final Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
                    try {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    long futuretime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futuretime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(futuretime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mCamera.release();
                    ine++;
```

Comment: please check this : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/

Comment: Same thing :/ Did not help. Thanks anyways